# Admin/backend and frontends as one project or separate projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm developing a front end with reactjs for a fairly large project which has two main interfaces.front-end of the main site and front-end of the admin.

Should i develop these as two different projects or one project in reactjs. if i structure these as two separate projects i'm well aware that it means i will have to do lot of repeating code on both projects. So i presume i should consider it as one project as below.

client (Project Folder)

- app/main
- app/admin

If i'm developing this as one project how do different front-ends route to different sub-domains if it lies in one project folder.

- example.com - main front-end
- admin.example.com - admin front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay to have a shared codebase for admin and public sites. But you will need to generate different js/css bundles for them. So your public `index.html` includes something like `public.js` and `public.css`. And the admin uses `admin.js` and `admin.css`. The public files contain all the shared functionality and the stuff which is used on the public site only. Same thing for admin.

Making that separation can significantly reduce the file sizes, as typically admin apps include some charts, rich text editors, css frameworks and tons of other stuff which may affect your public site loading speed.

To implement separate bundles with webpack, which you probably use, you need to create a few independent **entry points**.

The docs — https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html

Also, you will need to use different react-router setups and redux stores (if you use those). But the presentational components and utilities can be shared.